# Trouble getting USB printer to 'stick' using udevadm

Tags: usb, udev, printer

#### What I’ve got so far

```
$ udevadm info -a -p$(udevadm info --q path -n /dev/usb/lp1) | grep serial
ATTRS{serial}=="544336460792090000"
```

`/etc/udev/rules.d/50-udev.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{serial}=="544336460792090000", SYMLINK+="receipt"
```

Which does create a /dev/receipt link, but I get nothing when I try

```
echo -e 'foo' > /dev/receipt
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you do `echo -e 'foo' > /dev/usb/lp1`, does it actually print anything? Most printers need specifically formatted data sent to them.